# $_SESSION variable not accessible in Zen cart pages

Tags: php, cart, zen

I have been using $_SESSION variable in different folder than Zen cart installation folder. When I set the $_SESSION folder in any file and try to access it inside EZ Pages of Zen cart I get nothing.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a different folder to that where you have your Zen Cart installed, then you're probably not writing to the same session as the one where Zen Cart is storing its session data.

Zen Cart is pretty secure and has that well locked down to protect the data it holds. To access it your code would need to include Zen Cart's application_top file. However, that's near impossible to do from outside the Zen Cart includes folder.

Comment: Any solution for this. I am stuck with this session issue.